# BrE: 'screeching like an alley cat'

Tags: meaning, british-english

I have been learning British English. I found a sentence in a TV series:

'I heard an alley cat screeching.'

also

'Stop screeching like an alley cat!'

However, I don't quite understand the meaning. I have googled 'alley cat', but it turned out that 'alley cat' is a bar... I guess 'screeching like an alley cat' may mean 'being very emotional' but I am not sure. Could anyone tell me what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Alley cat" is a synonym for a stray cat, specifically one that lurks around in urban or suburban places, typically shown looking through garbage for food. The word "alley" describes a passageway that results from two buildings being built adjacent to each other in a town or city. The speaker is demanding that the "screecher" be more quiet in the second sentence, and is making a simple observation in the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

An *alley cat* is a feral cat inhabiting an urban area; i.e. a  *stray cat* one might find [scavenging](http://www.feralcatbehavior.com/380/theres-a-stray-outside.html) for food in alleys.

It is a television and film trope that such cats are [unpleasantly noisy](http://www.canidae.com/blog/2010/03/night-calling-why-do-cats-meow-at-night.html) while fighting, mating, calling for mates, or being prevented from mating, and human residents in the area have little recourse but to throw a show into the alley to attempt to frighten them off.